# Data Structure for Range Matching Lookup

Tags: json, algorithm, data-structures

Assume I have a structure of ranges, and their associated data, for instance:

```
data [
    [ [0, 100], "New York"],
    [ [101, 200], "Boston"],
    ...
]
```

For a function that receives a `N` as an arguments and returns the entry where `N` is in the range of the left element.

for instance,

```
> 103
< "Boston"
```

What will be the best structure to transform the above to achieve the fastest lookup time?

Answer (score 3):

If your data set should be dynamic, use [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try with B+ tree. As I haven't personally tried this problem either. B+ tree can have array as its child so you could set the data value for index 0-100 as New York with 101 pointing to child 2 in the tree.

Check about B+ tree [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)

I would recommend you to take regular approach for this, incase your data is small.